# How do I write a PostGIS update statement that ignores invalid geometries?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I wrote up a quick PL/pgSQL script that creates two new columns for `centroid_longitude` and `centroid_latitude` and uses data from a PostGIS geometry column and the `ST_X()`, `ST_Y()`, and `ST_Centroid()` PostGIS functions to calculate the values.

```
alter table nhd_hr_nhdwaterbody ADD COLUMN centroid_latitude numeric(19,11);
alter table nhd_hr_nhdwaterbody ADD COLUMN centroid_longitude numeric(19,11);
UPDATE nhd_hr_nhdwaterbody SET centroid_longitude=ST_X(ST_Centroid(geom)), centroid_latitude=ST_Y(ST_Centroid(geom));
```

When I run the script for a database that has several million entries, I get the following error.

```
ERROR:  lwgeom_centroid: GEOS Error: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4
```

As the error clearly states, the script is having an issue because `ST_Centroid()` requires that a geometry has 0 points or >= 4, but some of my data do not have that many points.  For my current application, I would just like to skip the entries that do not meet the criteria of having 0 or greater than or equal to 4 points.

Is there a way for me to modify this script so that the invalid geometries simply have their latitude and longitude values set to null?

Example Geometry:

"01060000A0E610000001000000010300008001000000090000002CCEE69D9E9151C0286E1A1F3E3C46400000000000000000682D06E09F9151C0C0E9DF28403C46400000000000000000A48D6E9F9F9151C078231061423C464000000000000000009C9D35FF9E9151C0B848616C433C46400000000000000000C88E061C9D9151C020568951433C4640000000000000000008A4F59B9C9151C0B8CFD508433C4640000000000000000060C4A6B09C9151C0004FD209423C464000000000000000003884B6DB9C9151C0088727EE3F3C464000000000000000002CCEE69D9E9151C0286E1A1F3E3C46400000000000000000"

Comment: Have you tried adding a filter using the ST_IsValid function? (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html)

Comment: Could you add a sample of these problematic geometries?

Comment: @JimJones I've added an example geometry. As in my comment to @jjanes, I found that using `ST_MakeValid` resolved my issues.

Comment: hey @MaxFeinberg. Do you really need to use MULTIPOLYGON Z? Your `Z` dimension is constantly zero.

Comment: @JimJones I have to use MULTIPOLYGON Z because the table is procedurally generated from a large data source that is updated monthly and contains data of varying resolution and detail.  Many of the column entries do have z-dimension values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a WHERE clause which tests the number of points (untested):

```
UPDATE nhd_hr_nhdwaterbody SET 
   centroid_longitude=ST_X(ST_Centroid(geom)), 
   centroid_latitude=ST_Y(ST_Centroid(geom))
WHERE NOT ST_NumPoints(geom) between 1 and 3;
```

The co-ords for the ones that don't get updated should remain NULL.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I tried your solution and I realized that the vast majority of my geometries were invalid.  What I ended up doing was using `ST_MakeValid(geom)` to create a new column of valid geometries and then `ST_Centroid` worked as expected.